# i want to call two different class "You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream"

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, django-rest-framework

i want to call two different class from one class in *viewset* of Django

```
class SocialLoginViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    def social_login(self, request):
        email = request.data['email']
        if email:
            user_qs = MobileUser.objects.filter(email__iexact=email, is_active=True)
            if user_qs.exists():
                ExtendedJSONWebTokenAPIView.as_view()(self.request)
            else:
                NormalUserCreateViewSet.as_view()(self.request)
```

both viewset i am calling through **Post** method

Comment: You approach looks bad. This exception exists for reason and you incorrectly use DRF and its layers of abstraction. But if you don't care you can workaround it by using `request.raw_post_data` instead of `request.data`.

Answer (score 0):

For various reasons, Django only allows reading POST body once.

Check out this answer:
[Exception: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581110/exception-you-cannot-access-body-after-reading-from-requests-data-stream)