# Unable to get base64 data in POST request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-post, cropperjs

I'm having trouble while reading data from POST request.

[Request screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPvLH.png)

It seems everything is fine from frontend but when I'm getting nothing 
 when trying to read the request data on the backend.

```
request.FILES
<MultiValueDict: {}>

request.POST
<QueryDict: {}>

request.body
*** RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
```

> Backend view code

```
def upload_file(request):   
  upload_response = requests.post(requestbuilder.create_request('/files'), files={request.FILES['file']._name:request.FILES['file']}, headers=requestbuilder.MULTIPART_HEADERS)
  return HttpResponse(upload_response.json().get('fileUrl'))
```

> Options for ajax call

```
var options = {
    url: "/apps/upload/",
    method: 'post',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    clickable: false,
    maxFiles: config.maxFiles,
    minWidth: config.minWidth,
    minHeight: config.minHeight,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
    },
   }
```

I'm completely blank, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post all the backend process please ?

Comment: Currently, I'm just trying to read the data from request's object but I'm stuck on the same.

Comment: You're using django rest framework ? can you show the serializers or the form definition?

Comment: @Bestasttung I'm not using any serializer. even not added rest-framework in the app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581110/exception-you-cannot-access-body-after-reading-from-requests-data-stream

Comment: I've already gone through above question but didn't find anything useful for me.

Comment: how are you calling this url? with a custom form? show code. With curl? show command. With python requests? show code

Comment: I'm using a library called cropper.js, It invokes an ajax call when an Icon Image is cropped.