# Django - RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream

Tags: django, python-3.x, request, jwt

I'm really stuck at this problem for a couple of days now.

While I understand, what's happening here, I don't really know the best workaround/solution for this.

**Problem:**

I'm trying to create a user login endpoint using Django and DRF in general.

My login API needs to support a login via password as well as login via OTP.

My `LoginView` looks like:

```
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    """
    post
        Method to handle user login
    :param request:
    :param args:
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """
    request_data = request.data
    login_using_password = request_data.get('login-with-password') is True
    login_using_otp = request_data.get('login-with-otp') is True
    if request_data is not None:
        if all((login_using_password, login_using_otp)):
            raise accounts_exceptions.InvalidLoginRequestError()
        if login_using_password:
            return Response(self._login_with_password(request))
        elif login_using_otp:
            return Response(self._login_with_otp(request))
        raise accounts_exceptions.InvalidLoginRequestError()
    return Response(self._login_with_password(request))
```

Also my `_login_with_password` looks like:

```
    def _login_with_password(self, request, **kwargs):
    """
    _login_with_password
        A utility method to handle login with password
    :param request:
    :return:
    """
    return getattr(ObtainJSONWebToken.as_view()(request=request._request, ), 'data')
```

When I try to login, `Django` complains saying `RawPostDataException You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream`

I'm using `JWT` to authenticate requests. `ObtainJSONWebToken` is a view provided by DRF-JWT to obtain access tokens to authenticate requests.

What is the workaround/solution for this?

Is there a better way to support such a login requirement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found answer, and write it here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77488327/12060672) (doesn't want to dublicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this.

There's no concrete way to solve the problem above.

Django disallows access to `request.data` multiple times.

It could be done only once for the entire request lifetime.

So, this left me with two solutions:

1. Move my request payload to `query params`.
2. Move my request payload to `url context`.

I ended up using a mix and match of both.

So, basically I used `request.query_params` and `self.context` to fetch data from the request and changed my URL and request structure accordingly.