# access data from request body django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using `django v2.2.4` and need to access request body data.

Here's my code:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        results= []
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = ScrapeSerializer(data=data)

        if serializer.is_valid():           
            url = request.data.url
            #url = request.POST.get('url')
```

But I get this error:

```
RawPostDataException at /scrape/
You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
```

Here's the request body:

```
{
    "url": "xyz.com"
}
```

How can I access the request body?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this SO post that related to this issue, [**Exception: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581110/exception-you-cannot-access-body-after-reading-from-requests-data-stream)

Anyway use [**`request.data`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data) instead of **`request.body`** in DRF

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        results = []
        serializer = ScrapeSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            url = request.data["url"]
```

The **`request.data`** returns **the parsed content of the request body** and it will be ***dict like object***, hence the ***dot operation (`request.data.url`)*** won't works here.

Answer (score 0):

To access the request body of a POST request, you could do this by `url = request.POST.get("url")`