# django.http.request.RawPostDataException on file upload

Tags: python, django, debugging, django-rest-framework

When I try to upload a file to my Django application and try to get the body of the request, I get this error.

`File "/docs/geon/tenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 330, in body raise RawPostDataException("You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream") django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream`

Then I tried using the debugger to inspect the middleware by creating a simple middleware that does nothing and adding it to the topmost place in the list of middleware, then adding a breakpoint just after entering the process_request function. Then I inspected the 'body' attribute of the request and it is
`RawPostDataException("You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream")`

Apparently, something is modifying the request before it gets to middleware at all, and if the body is empty, it should be an empty string and not raise an error. I don't know which stack before middleware to look.

I have restframework installed in app if it means something

Comment: Share your views bro.

Comment: The request hasn't gotten to my view. The request has the error in the body attribute before even getting to the first middleware.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581110/exception-you-cannot-access-body-after-reading-from-requests-data-stream)

Comment: No it doesn't. The question suggested "request.data" to replace "request.body" which gives this error ```AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data```